# How to extract the parameter from Json Response Using Groovy?

Tags: soapui

The below is my response..

```
{"activation":{"existing":false, "customer": new}}
```

Now when I use

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getPropertyValue("response")
```

The above script is extracting the response. Now I wanted to extract `"customer"` value.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("xxx").getPropertyValue("response")
slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
log.info (slurperresponse.activation.customer)
```

Comment: In addition, I would pass `activation.customer` as a dynamic value, as these values change for different json response.