# SOAP UI Property Transfer - Parse JSON and read parameter

Tags: json, soap, xpath, integration-testing, soapui

I am trying to parse a json response received in the previous Test Step, read a parameter's value from it, and use it in the next Test Step. I am clueless; I've been able to get the response ( The entire `JSON` ) into a property, however I tried using `XPath` with `ResponseAsXml`, but it always says "Missing Match for source `XPath`".

Here is the JSON response received in the previous Test Step:

```
{
  "access_token": "f4808125fc054de969a0cbe9ddec1ec3",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "27c83771b36a0509873a7c7a3137b22d"
}
```

I would like to read `access_token` here and transfer it to the next step. Any help will be really very appreciated.

Comment: Check out json slurper and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585063/how-to-extract-the-parameter-from-json-response-using-groovy. The op there has asked the same question.

Comment: XPath is language to query XML but not JSON. I think, link to question provided above answers your question.

Comment: That is not same as my question. My question is about property transfer *where Groovy cannot be used at all*. The question you liked to talks about parsing json in *Script Assertions*. They are not the same. Please don't get this wrong.

Comment: @olyv, I am aware that XPath works with XML and not JSON. Check my question again, I've mentioned `XPath` with `ResponseAsXml`, not JSON.

Comment: I am answering my own question hoping it would help someone someday. 
I selected ResponseAsXml and then put in `//*:access_token` in the `XPath` code. It was able to select that element right away. Unfortunately no one has been able to distinguish this question from the one linked to as original.